# In the Bloom County universe, can all animals talk, or are Opus and co. the exceptions?

Tags: bloom-county

In Berkley Breathed's Bloom County, Opus and his friends (Bill the cat etc) have the power of speech. Do all animals in that universe have this power, or is it something unique to Opus (and his friends)?

Comment: Technically Bill the Cat can't talk.  It's part of his being a parody of Garfield.

Comment: Bill the Cat can talk if it's important enough.  He manages to tell the band to "sell out" at the beginning of *Tales Too Ticklish to Tell*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No, all animals cannot talk. Opus is an exception.

This comic makes that quite clear:

[image]

(I remembered this from years ago, but couldn't remember the date. I went through 3 books to find this.)

Comment: Forced to go through 3 Bloom County books - what a travesty!

Answer (score 6):

The default in *Bloom County* seems to be that animals can talk.  While Opus started out as a non-speaking pet penguin, by the time he became the strip's central character, the conceit of the comic seemed to have changed to one in which animals were normally sentient (and eligible to vote, based on the Meadow Party's multiple presidential campaigns).

Even [Bill the Cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_the_Cat), known for generally saying only "Ack!" and hacking up hairballs, was capable of saying, "Sell out!" when advertisers offered to turn his song "[U Stink, But I ♥ U](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=odUt-lDH85k)" into an TV jingle.  So in Bill's case (in spite of his originating as an *in-universe* knock-off/parody of Garfield), his lack of normal speech may have been due to his obscenely bad health habits, rather than anything innate.  Moreover, I do not think there were any instances of animals being shows as being specifically incapable of speech.

The use of animals for food might seem to [cause problems for this](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CarnivoreConfusion), but apparently, the *Bloom County* universe got along fine with sentient creatures being used for meat.  For example, there does not seem to be a distinction between animals that can talk and game animals to be hunted.  After [Rosebud the basselope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_characters_in_Bloom_County#Rosebud_the_Basselope) was discovered (the last survivor or her kind), there was a strip that contrasted the hunters who went after her (crying "Shoot!  Shoot!") with the television reporters who wanted to get her on tape (also running after her, yelling "Shoot!  Shoot!).

Finally, to add to the confusion, the *Bloom County* universe has two separate meta layers.  In most strips, the characters we see are actually actors, working for [W. A. Thornhump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_characters_in_Bloom_County#W._A._Thornhump_III), the C.E.O. of *Bloom County Industries* (which was eventually bought out by Donald Trump in Bill the Cat's body, after Trump's yacht accidentally dropped an anchor on him).  Opus is a talking penguin *actor* in the meta world.  Sometimes, however, the figures appearing in the strip are actually the actors themselves, going off script (for example, getting Attorney General Ed Meese to pull the comic because they said "Snugglebunnies"—a word associted with high rates of murder, uncle abuse, and dog hickeys—too often).  In general, which version of Opus/Milo/Steve Dallas/etc. appeared was dictated purely by what Berke Breathed thought would be funny.  Sometimes, the action was said to be scripted; other times, the characters were evidently part of a reality show (before reality shows really became a thing).

Comment: +1 for Rosebud. Ah, the dangers of buttered pip-tarts...